# WCErrorCodePayloadTooLarge - Payload is too large

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to make a **WatchOS app** that can receive images and a title from a iPhone app in SwiftUI.
I create a object that has SecureCoding. The object is called TemplateObject that can have a String and an array of Data.
I convert the images of the iPhone to data and send to Watch as TemplateObject
`let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: template, requiringSecureCoding: true)`
The image that I was testing has 51kB.
Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

for image transfer to watch always use the `WCSession` method

```
- (WCSessionFileTransfer *)transferFile:(NSURL *)file metadata:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)metadata;
```

we should transfer only a small amount of data through other methods of `WCSession`